# How to lock accounts after n distinct password attempts, not just n attemps of potentially the same data

Tags: passwords, distinct, policy, lockout

Hi there stack exchange,

We're seeing numerous issues in our environment of misconfigured systems repeatedly trying old passwords and causing the accounts to be locked out.

I can see no value in locking out accounts where the same password is tried multiple times, this does not get a (potential) attacker any closer to guessing the password as far as I can work out?  I would like to know if there is a way to securely configure a system to count the number of distinct/unique password attempts per user, rather than just the number of attempts before lockout occurs?

I can appriciate that recording password attempts using a reversable derivitive might be bad for security, but surely there's a way to distinguish if the same password is attempted multiple times?  Recording recent attempts in a long hash or something?

At the very least is it possible for a system to know that the immediately previous password has been attempted, or even a few back, and not count those as failed attempts?  I have seen this implemented and it would seem simmilar to the need to judge uniqueness/distinction?

If the only purpose of a lockout policy is to prevent online brute force password guessing, rather than as a tool to DoS accounts, why is incrementing failed logon counters after only distinct password attempts uncommon?

Lots of question marks sorry, but for clarity the main question is again;

I would like to know if there is a way to securely configure a system to count the number of distinct/unique password attempts per user, rather than just the number of attempts before lockout occurs?

Thanks for any thoughts!

Kind regards,
Xeotech

Comment: Why would you need a *reversible* derivative?  Why not a suitably-hashed derivative?

Comment: Yeh sorry about my spelling, so no, you wouldn't _want_ a reversible version, but storing a hash allows the password to be brute forced offline if compromised.  Or passwords for other systems entered in error, or revealing password creation strategies when analysed collectively, or some other angle I'm not seeing.I appriciate with the right precautions this can be mitigated to a large degree but I thought perhaps that was held as a justification of retaining no record of previous attempts.